# Appending routes in React Router

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I have a homepage something like banana.com/home which contains some items. On the homepage, if I apply filters the URL changes to banana.com/home?brand=abc. Now I navigate to one of the items on the homepage which is a new route, like banana.com/itemid=1. Every item has a back button that should navigate me back to the homepage but I want to retain the filters. What I ideally want is that my route should look like banana.com/home?brand=abc/itemid=1.

Not using redux and would like to avoid sessionStorage/localStorage.

How do I make this happen?

EDIT: In my code, I have a variable that stores the query param but when I navigate to the item (new route), the variable changes to "".

Comment: Please share the code you use to update the query params and your route configs

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share the code due to confidentiality.. :(

Comment: Inn that case, try to replicate the same scenario with a minimum reproducible example on codesandbox. You need not copy confidential code but its important to know how you are implementing it to be able to provide a proper solution